# multiple right click contextmenu angularjs

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, contextmenu, right-click

[image]

i m trying to implement a dropdown on right click using this directive [contextMenu](https://github.com/bapatel1/bp-ngContextMenu)  in angularjs. This directive works fine in firefox but doesnt close the old menu while opening a different one when using ' google chrome'. Any idea how can i make changes to it.
Here is the [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LMr7AN?p=info)

```
(function(angular) {
  var ngContextMenu = angular.module('directive.contextMenu', []);

  ngContextMenu.directive('cellHighlight', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
     iElement.find('td')
       .mouseover(function() {
         $(this).parent('tr').css('opacity', '0.7');
       }).mouseout(function() {
         $(this).parent('tr').css('opacity', '1.0');
       });
     }
 };
});

ngContextMenu.directive('context', [

function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: '@&',
    compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
      return {
        post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
          var ul = $('#' + iAttrs.context),
            last = null;

          ul.css({
            'display': 'none'
          });
          $(iElement).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
             ul.css({
              position: "fixed",
              display: "block",
              left: event.clientX + 'px',
              top: event.clientY + 'px'
            });
            last = event.timeStamp;
          });
          //$(iElement).click(function(event) {
          //  ul.css({
          //    position: "fixed",
          //    display: "block",
          //    left: event.clientX + 'px',
          //    top: event.clientY + 'px'
          //  });
          //  last = event.timeStamp;
          //});

          $(document).click(function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if (!target.is(".popover") && !target.parents().is(".popover")) {
              if (last === event.timeStamp)
                return;
              ul.css({
                'display': 'none'
              });
            }
          });
        }
      };
    }
     };
     }
  ]);
   })(window.angular);
```

Comment: plunkr looks working in my google Chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the .click event to .mouseup event and it will work with chrome.

```
 $(document).mouseup(function(event) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            if (!target.is(".popover") && !target.parents().is(".popover")) {
              if (last === event.timeStamp)
                return;
              ul.css({
                'display': 'none'
              });
            }
          });
```

I faced the same problem, and it worked for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code (of the directive), I think this context menu directive is a little bit too simple. It simply doesn't do a whole lot more than triggering a show/hide on the element referenced by the `context` attribute. It may have been enough for the use case of the one who wrote it, but it appears to be too lightweight for a general solution.

What is happening in the directive code: If you happened to trigger a context menu on the same row (or more general reference the same context menu) it works correctly because it will simply show the current context menu at a different place. If you trigger `context1` first and then (by clicking on the second row) trigger a different context menu `context2` there simply isn't any code that would trigger a hide of the `context1` context menu.

You could implement this yourself as well but then keep track of any already opened context menu's and close them before another one is opened.

Btw: this context menu doesn't work for me in Firefox (38, Mac OS X) either. It opens the context menu and immediately closes it again. This is probably because both the `contextmenu` (on the table row) and the `click` (on document) are triggered.